# DynamoDB Throughput vs Search time

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, throughput, capacity, aws-billing

I've just figured out a big mistake I had while creating the dynamodb structure.
I've created 11 tables, whereas one of them is the table mostly refereed to and the others are complementary tables.
For example, I have a table where I hold names (together with other info) called "Names" and another table called "NamesMappings" holding all these names added to the "Names" table so that each time a user wants to add a name to the "Names" table he first tries to put the name in "NamesMappings" and only if it succeed (therefore this name doesn't exist) he can add the name into the "Names" table. This procedure helps if the name is not unique and is not the primary key in the "Names" table and with this technique I don't have to search inside the "Names" table if the name exists, but instead I can try to add it to the "NamesMappings" table and only if it succeed I know this is a unique name.

First of all, I would like to ask you if this is a common approach or there is a better one?

Next, I figured out that with this design I soon reached to 11 tables each has 5 provisioned capacity of read and write which leads to overall 55 provisioned read and write under the free-tier. Then I understood why I get all these payments each month, because as the number of tables is getting bigger, and I leave the provisioned capacity as default (both read/write capacity are 5) I get more and more provisioned capacity.

So, what should be my conclusion from this understanding? Should I try to reduce the number of tables even if it takes more effort to preform scanning and querying inside the table? Or should I split the table same as I do but reduce the capacity of these mappings tables used only for indication if an item exists or not in another table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you're missing the whole concept of NoSQL Databases.

Your `Names` table should have a Hash key (which is similar to a Primary key) that has a uniformly generated identifier (an UUID is a great candidate). This would automatically make this Table queryable by this unique identifier. You said, however, that you don't know the ID but you only know the Name instead. This leads me to think you could create a [Global Secondary Index (GSI)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html) on the `Name` attribute inside the `Names` table so you can also query by `Name`. Up to this point, your table structure should look like this:

`id | name`

Both of them are independently queryable, which gives you a lot of flexibility already.

Now, let's say you want to add the `NameMapping` attribute (which I don't know how it looks like), you can simply add it under the `Names` table, getting rid of the `NamesMappings` table, greatly reducing the number of WCUs and RCUs across your account. Your table structure should now look like this:

`id | name | mappings`

where `mappings` is, let's say, a JSON object.

Since you can only query on top level attributes in DynamoDB, you can now perform a query against the `name` attribute which has a GSI configured. If the query returns nothing, then `name` is unique. But let's say you still need some data inside the `mappings` object, then you could query by `name` and, *in your code*, you could apply a map/filter/reduce operation on the `mappings` attribute and decide what to do next.

Remember that *duplication is just OK* in a NoSQL world. This may look scary if you come from a purely SQL background, but data should be stored in such a way in NoSQL databases that you should be able to fetch all the needed information in one go, therefore avoiding "*joins*" (joins are still possible in a NoSQL database, but since there are no strong relationships between entities, you need to perform these joins manually on the code level). To give you some real context, imagine you have a `Orders` table where you keep track of the ordered Products and the Store that the Order belongs to: you'd save both the Products and the Store objects (and not their IDs, as it would happen in the SQL way) inside the Order object, so if you want to query for a given OrderId in the future, you wouldn't need to make extra calls (aka "*joins*") to the Product/Store tables to fetch the information, since everything would already be stored inside the Order object.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think I didn't explain myself correctly. Say I have a table with ID and name as you suggested above. Now inside the table I have two record: (Record 1) ID = GUID1, Name = "A" and (Record 2) ID = GUID2, Name = "B". Now a user tried to add a new record with the Name "A". I wouldn't want to query this "Names" table and look for the Name "A" to see if it exists, instead I would want to put the item inside another table which only has one column holding the names that were already added. So in this case this table will have the records "A" and "B". So if someone

Comment: tries to put "A" inside the other table again he will fail because "A" is already there and therefore without quering the "Names" table (only by using put on the other table) I was able to avoid duplicates. Is this thinking correct?

Comment: I really don't understand why you'd want to keep an extra table if the information is already available on the `Names` table. What do you think you gain by inserting data into another table if that information is already queryable on the `Names` table? Because you need to check the information anyways, either on `Names` or `NamesMapping`. Maybe I am missing something in your problem, but the only thing I see is that `name` on `NamesMapping` would be a hash key, so it'd fail because of the hash key constraint without the need to check whether it exists or not. (continues...)

Comment: ...but `name` is not a good hash key and also it costs you more as you need to provision RCUs and WCUs for two tables rather than one. You may be overcomplicating things a little bit. I still think that querying `name` on the `Names` table via a GSI is more flexible as well as cheaper. It also reduces complexity.

Comment: Okay thank you very much I think I understand your point. You are correct I really complicated here the design. Only one thing, why do I need GSI ? Can't I just query the Name column and look for the new name going to be added to the table and see if there is a Name equals to the new name to be added?

Comment: Glad I could help. No, if you don't create a GSI on the attribute you want to query by you need to perform a scan (which is a very costly operation). So when you need to query by an attribute which is not your hash key neither your sort key, the solution is to create a Global Secondary Index on it

Comment: Thank very very much for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: If there is a chance and you are still here, I just now noticed that the other tables that hold the names is a combination of two columns from the "Names" table. Can I still achieve the result with GSI?  My solution was that on each insert to the "Names" table I take these two columns values and add them together to one string inside another table. So for example if inside the "Names" table I have two columns with the values 1 and 2, then inside the other table I will have one column with the value 12. So that next time if someone tries to enter the same values 1 and 2 to the "names" table he

Comment: will fail to do that because the other table already have item with the value 12

Comment: I would query on the GSI (name) and filter out the values on the code level. So if you are trying to insert "My|Name" I would query for "My" and see if the corresponding values match "Name". If not, then it is unique.

Comment: Great, Actually I think I could have save a column inside the "Names" table called "UniquenessColumn" and hold there the combination values I saved on the other table and make this column a sort key so that I will be able to query by this column. Although my solution is less scalable and if tomorrow I will need a different uniquness combination I will have some issues. Thank you!